# Python Brute wildcard

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, wildcard

Hello I am trying to make a simple letter brute force for pentesting:

```
    astric = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g','h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
    usern = input("username you want to check with '*' for unknown chars: ")
    paramsGet = {"Name": usern}
```

So the input would be asking what username and I'd put `meep**` and then it would assign the astric list random letters or numbers to the list so then it would be a full request. How do I go about this?
`for _ in list:`
I assume its something like that

Comment: You can use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), and change the real `*` to the `astric` values. In any case `list(itertools.product(*[astric if char == '*' else [char] for char in usern]))`, would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a recursive approach for the problem.

```py
def getWords(words):
    matched_words = []
    break_flag = True
    for word in words:
        if '*' not in word:
            matched_words.append(word)
        else:
            break_flag = False
            for char in astric:
                matched_words.append(word.replace('*', char, 1))
    if break_flag:
        return matched_words
    else:
        return getWords(matched_words)
print(getWords(["meep*"]))
```

In effect, it accepts a list of words and checks for an `*` and replaces it with each character in the character list `astric` and recurses for further `*`s

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
astric = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g','h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
usern = input("username you want to check with '*' for unknown chars: ")
paramsGet = {"Name": usern}

def get(usern):
    if len(usern) == 0:
        yield ''
        return
    head, tail = usern[0], usern[1:]
    for each in get(tail):
        if head == '*':
            for c in astric:
                yield c + each
        else:
            yield head + each

for each in get(usern):
    print(each)
```

I do not think it is the best approach and not the fastest

Answer (score 0):

You can take note of the index of each asterisk.

```py
asterisk_location = [i for i, x in enumerate(source) if x == "*"]
```

You can leverage [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to handle generating all possible pairs with repeats based on the number of asterisks present.

```py
product(astric, repeat=len(asterisk_location))
```

Then you can just replace each value at the known asterisk index with one of the values generated by itertools.

```py
source[index] = value
```

All together you end up with something like:

```py
from itertools import product
from typing import Generator

astric = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
          'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x',
          'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']


def generate_possible_options(source: str) -> Generator[str, None, None]:
    source = list(source)
    asterisk_location = [i for i, x in enumerate(source) if x == "*"]
    for option in product(astric, repeat=len(asterisk_location)):
        for index, value in zip(asterisk_location, option):
            source[index] = value
        yield ''.join(source)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for possibility in generate_possible_options("m*ep*"):
        print(possibility)
```

Naturally, you can add user input and pass the results to the `generate_possible_options` function, but I've kept it as a static value so that it can be easily copied and run without hanging for user input.

This generated 1296 possible options.

Abbreviated Output:

```
maepa
maepb
maepc
maepd
maepe
maepf
maepg
maeph
maepi
maepj
maepk
maepl
...
m9ep2
m9ep3
m9ep4
m9ep5
m9ep6
m9ep7
m9ep8
m9ep9
```

You can also get the list object by:

```py
possibilities = list(generate_possible_options("m*ep*"))
```